# sometime the cmake -LA will change some config parameters, sometimes it does not, why?

Tags: cmake

I try to export some cmake variables into bash, so I used cmake -LA. I many case this will work, but for some packages, the cmake -LA will change the variable values set by -D... in previous cmake calling.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `-LA` still executes the CMake script as usual.

So if, for instance you do something like

```
if(FOO)
    set(FOO FALSE CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
else()
    set(FOO TRUE CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
endif()
```

You will see a different value for `FOO` each run.

You can disable execution of the script by adding the [`-N` parameter](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html):

```
cmake -LA -N <path_to_source>
```